Prime-entangled Addition
My intuition tells me:
if
(original question: $x$, $y$ and $z$ are all integers)
edit: $x$, $y$ and $z$ are all positive integers greater than 2
$x$ and $y$ divide into $z$ (with integer results)
$x \neq y$
then
$x+y+z$
will have prime factors that are not factors of $z$
I have looked into modular arithmetic, combinatorics (particularly necklaces) and Fermat's Little Theorem and they all seem related, but I'm having trouble putting it all together.
Proof as to the veracity (either way) of my intuition would be gratefully received, and any advice on similar problems I could study to aid my learning would also be very helpful.

It's false, for example for $x=3$, $y=6$, $z=18$.
(Answer for original question: It's false, for example for $x=1$, $y=-1$, $z=1$.)
More counterexamples:
3 6 18
3 12 12
4 8 24
5 10 10
6 24 24
7 14 28
7 21 21
10 20 20

We can see a pattern for infinitely many: For any prime $p \ge 5$ you get the counterexample $x=p$, $y=2p$, $z=(p-3)p$, as $x+y+z=p^2$ only has prime factor $p$, which is a factor of $z$.
The above list was found with this:
stop = 30

P = [p for p in range(2, 3*stop) if all(p % d for d in range(2, p))]

for x in range(3, stop):
  for y in range(x+1, stop):
    for z in range(x, stop, x):
      if not z % y:
        if not any(not (x+y+z)%p and z%p for p in P):
          print(x, y, z)

Attempt This Online!

Thank you - I have updated the question to clarify positive integers

@Abulafia Added more counterexamples.
